# Stackwalk get Function Name, Line number and File Name, in debug

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, stack, names

## Quick summary

In a nut shell i wish to access the debug information regarding the stack, preferably for passing information to Logger.

I wish for the information to tell me the **Function Name**, **Line Number** and **File Name**.

I've got the symbols and i'm attempting to access the junk values in them and turn them in to English. However nothing seems to work.

I have commented the code for people to read and see if they can help me effectively walk the stack to pull the information out i need.

- So far  i can point out `SymGetModuleBase()` does not return a positive number only 0, according to MSDN it fails if returns 0. Which is correct as it returns a memory address.
- `SymGetSymFromAddr()` fails to return true, which i'm assuming gets the name of the stack frame/function
- `SymGetLineFromAddr()` goes on to fail as well and doesn't return the line number location in the file and also doesn't gather the file path.

I believe this is due to the `process` parameter being invalid. I will elaborate below.

### Attempts to locate and fix the problem

- I have read the MSDN documentation repeatedly and feel like i'm banging my head off the wall, i've done pretty much what it said and i feel like it's just not working.
- However i have noticed `SymInitialize()` should be called prior to attempting this, which i do call. This changed the `GetLastError()` value from 6 `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` to 0 `ERROR_SUCCESS`. Yet `SymGetModuleBase()` still returns 0 no matter if `SymInitialize()` although `GetLastError()` reports different error codes depending on `SymInitialize()` use. It should return a valid virtual memory address this is where i think the main problem lies in the code.
- `HANDLE process = ::GetCurrentProcess();` this line in the code below returns `0xffffffffffffffff` very suspect if you ask me. This should return a pseudo virtual memory address but it to me anyway looks like a false result. This happens every time i run the program which leads me to think `::GetCurrentProcess()` this is either got a bug, or doesn't work somehow. According to MSDN this is the correct a up to date way of getting the current process and i don't know how to get a valid `HANDLE` to a the process another way. So i can't pass the first parameter in `SymGetModuleBase()` the correct process, although i maybe wrong.

**Full code for the function**

```
void Logger::WriteStackFrames(log::TextColor tc)
{
    // Initalize some memory
    DWORD                           machine = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64;
    HANDLE                          process = ::GetCurrentProcess();
    HANDLE                          thread = GetCurrentThread();

    // Initalize more memory
    CONTEXT                         context;
    STACKFRAME                      stack_frame;

    // Set some memory
    memset(&context, 0, sizeof(CONTEXT));
    memset(&stack_frame, 0, sizeof(STACKFRAME));

    // Capture the context
    RtlCaptureContext(&context);

    // Initalize a few things here and there
    stack_frame.AddrPC.Offset       = context.Rip;
    stack_frame.AddrPC.Mode         = AddrModeFlat;
    stack_frame.AddrStack.Offset    = context.Rsp;
    stack_frame.AddrStack.Mode      = AddrModeFlat;
    stack_frame.AddrFrame.Offset    = context.Rbp;
    stack_frame.AddrFrame.Mode      = AddrModeFlat;

    // Randomly saw this was supposed to be called prior to StackWalk so tried it
    if (!SymInitialize(process, 0, false))
    {
        wprintf(L"SymInitialize unable to find process!! Error: %d\r\n", GetLastError());
    }

    for (ULONG frame = 0; ; frame++)
    {
        // Set text color
        SetTextColor(tc);

        // Check for frames
        BOOL result = StackWalk(machine, process, thread, &stack_frame, &context, 0,
            SymFunctionTableAccess, SymGetModuleBase, 0);

        // Get memory address of base module. Returns 0 although when SymInitialize is called before it the GetLastError returns 0 without return 6
        DWORD64 module_base = SymGetModuleBase(process, stack_frame.AddrPC.Offset);
        if (module_base == 0) {
            wprintf(L"SymGetModuleBase is unable to get virutal address!! Error: %d\r\n", GetLastError());
        }

        // Initalize more memory
        MODULEINFO                  module_info;
        SecureZeroMemory(&module_info, sizeof(MODULEINFO));

        // Get the file name of the file containing the function
        TCHAR module_buffer[log::MaxPath];
        DWORD mod_file = GetModuleFileName((HINSTANCE)module_base, module_buffer, log::MaxPath);
        if ((module_base != 0) && (mod_file != 0))
        {
            module_info.module_name = module_buffer;
        }

        // Initalize more memory and clear it out
        PIMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64      symbol;
        IMAGEHLP_LINE64         line_num;
        SecureZeroMemory(&symbol, sizeof(PIMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64));
        SecureZeroMemory(&symbol, sizeof(IMAGEHLP_LINE64));

        // Get the symbol
        TCHAR symbol_buffer[log::MaxPath];
        symbol = (PIMAGEHLP_SYMBOL)symbol_buffer;
        symbol->SizeOfStruct = (sizeof(IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL) + log::MaxPath);
        symbol->MaxNameLength = 254;

        // Attempt to get name from symbol (fails)
        LPSTR name_buffer = new CHAR[254];
        if (SymGetSymFromAddr(process, stack_frame.AddrPC.Offset, 0, symbol))
        {
            name_buffer = symbol->Name;
        }

        // Set the size of something
        DWORD offset = 0;
        line_num.SizeOfStruct = sizeof(IMAGEHLP_LINE64);

        // Attempt to get the line and file name of where the symbol is
        if (SymGetLineFromAddr(process, stack_frame.AddrPC.Offset, &offset, &line_num))
        {
            module_info.line = line_num.LineNumber;
            module_info.file = line_num.FileName;
        }

        // Initalize memory
        LPWSTR console_message = new TCHAR[log::MaxMsgLength];
        LPWSTR file_message = new TCHAR[log::MaxMsgLength];

        // Set some strings
        swprintf(console_message, log::MaxMsgLength, L">> Frame %02lu: called from: %016X Stack: %016X Frame: %016X Address return: %016X\r\n",
            frame, stack_frame.AddrPC.Offset, stack_frame.AddrStack.Offset, stack_frame.AddrFrame.Offset, stack_frame.AddrReturn.Offset);
        swprintf(file_message, log::MaxMsgLength, L"Frame %02lu: called from: %016X Stack: %016X Frame: %016X Address return: %016X\r\n",
            frame, stack_frame.AddrPC.Offset, stack_frame.AddrStack.Offset, stack_frame.AddrFrame.Offset, stack_frame.AddrReturn.Offset);

        /* When the symbol can yield the name, line and file name the above strings
        will also include that information */
        // To go here . . . 

        // Write some strings
        wprintf(console_message);
        WriteAsync(file_message);

        // Delete some memory
        if (console_message) {
            delete[] console_message;   console_message = nullptr;
        }
        if (file_message) {
            delete[] file_message;  file_message = nullptr;
        }

        // If nothing else to do break loop
        if (!result) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

#### What i hope to achieve

Although i realize this will only work in debug mode that is fine, and i know i could write a macro using the `__LINE__ __FUNCTION__ __FILE__` macros but that isn't what i'm looking for.

The results should be a wind up from the bottom stack showing the memory addresses of the calling PC, stack and frame. This works.

However it should also show me which the Name of the function, the Line number and the File path. This doesn't work.

FYI: I realize i need to add the code in to the generate the string and output it, but the code isn't capable of getting the information for the strings so that isn't coded in yet.

Please if anyone can help me, it would be fantastic all the code is focused around the "DbgHelp.h" windows file and most information is available on MSDN. So for the long question but i felt i should provide everything i know.

Comment: GetCurrentProcess return -1 (0xffffffffffffffff), this is not suspicious.

Comment: also the thread will be 0xfffffffffffffffe which just seems to mean "your own thread"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
::GetCurrentProcess() = 0xffffffffffffffff
```

is not suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few variations on your code pulling bits from here and there - in the end I could not get it to work as I was using clang/mingw and it was not generating .pdb files. However, maybe the code will work for you as you are using MSVC. Anyway, here it is, in case it helps

I also noticed you hard coded machine type to AMD - I assume that is correct for you, but below I have an ifdef I found that sets it for other archs.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <excpt.h>
#include <imagehlp.h>
#include <binutils/bfd.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <dbghelp.h>

#define MAX_SYMBOL_LEN 1024

typedef struct CallstackEntry
{
    DWORD64 offset; // if 0, we have no valid entry
    CHAR    name[MAX_SYMBOL_LEN];
    CHAR    undName[MAX_SYMBOL_LEN];
    CHAR    undFullName[MAX_SYMBOL_LEN];
    DWORD64 offsetFromSmybol;
    DWORD   offsetFromLine;
    DWORD   lineNumber;
    CHAR    lineFileName[MAX_SYMBOL_LEN];
    DWORD   symType;
    LPCSTR  symTypeString;
    CHAR    moduleName[MAX_SYMBOL_LEN];
    DWORD64 baseOfImage;
    CHAR    loadedImageName[MAX_SYMBOL_LEN];
} CallstackEntry;

typedef enum CallstackEntryType
{
    firstEntry,
    nextEntry,
    lastEntry
} CallstackEntryType;

void _backtrace (void)
{
    HANDLE process = ::GetCurrentProcess();
    HANDLE thread = GetCurrentThread();

    if (!SymInitialize(process, 0, true)) {
        wprintf(L"SymInitialize unable to find process!! Error: %d\r\n",~
                GetLastError());
    }
   DWORD symOptions = SymGetOptions();
    symOptions |= SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES;
    symOptions |= SYMOPT_FAIL_CRITICAL_ERRORS;
    symOptions = SymSetOptions(symOptions);

    char szSearchPath[MAX_SYMBOL_LEN] = {0};
    SymGetSearchPath(process, szSearchPath, MAX_SYMBOL_LEN);

    char  szUserName[MAX_SYMBOL_LEN] = {0};
    DWORD dwSize = MAX_SYMBOL_LEN;
    GetUserNameA(szUserName, &dwSize);

    CHAR   search_path_debug[MAX_SYMBOL_LEN];
    size_t maxLen = MAX_SYMBOL_LEN;
#if _MSC_VER >= 1400
    maxLen = _TRUNCATE;
#endif
    _snprintf_s(search_path_debug, maxLen,~
                "SymInit: Symbol-SearchPath: '%s', symOptions: %d, UserName: '%s'\n",
                szSearchPath, symOptions, szUserName);
    search_path_debug[MAX_SYMBOL_LEN - 1] = 0;
    printf(search_path_debug);

    // Initalize more memory
    CONTEXT context;
    memset(&context, 0, sizeof(CONTEXT));
    context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
    RtlCaptureContext(&context);

    // Initalize a few things here and there
    STACKFRAME stack;
    memset(&stack, 0, sizeof(STACKFRAME));
    stack.AddrPC.Offset       = context.Rip;
    stack.AddrPC.Mode         = AddrModeFlat;
    stack.AddrStack.Offset    = context.Rsp;
    stack.AddrStack.Mode      = AddrModeFlat;
    stack.AddrFrame.Offset    = context.Rbp;
    stack.AddrFrame.Mode      = AddrModeFlat;

#ifdef _M_IX86
    auto machine = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386;
#elif _M_X64
    auto machine = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64;
#elif _M_IA64
    auto machine = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_IA64;
#else
#error "platform not supported!"
#endif
    for (ULONG frame = 0; ; frame++) {
        BOOL result = StackWalk(machine,~
                                process,~
                                thread,~
                                &stack,
                                &context,
                                0,
                                SymFunctionTableAccess,~
                                SymGetModuleBase,~
                                0);

        CallstackEntry csEntry;
        csEntry.offset = stack.AddrPC.Offset;
        csEntry.name[0] = 0;
        csEntry.undName[0] = 0;
        csEntry.undFullName[0] = 0;
        csEntry.offsetFromSmybol = 0;
        csEntry.offsetFromLine = 0;
        csEntry.lineFileName[0] = 0;
        csEntry.lineNumber = 0;
        csEntry.loadedImageName[0] = 0;
        csEntry.moduleName[0] = 0;

        IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64 symbol {};
        symbol.SizeOfStruct = sizeof(IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64);
        symbol.MaxNameLength = MAX_SYMBOL_LEN;

        // Initalize more memory and clear it out
        if (SymGetSymFromAddr64(process,~
                                stack.AddrPC.Offset,
                                &csEntry.offsetFromSmybol,~
                                &symbol)) {
        }

        IMAGEHLP_LINE64 line {};
        line.SizeOfStruct = sizeof(line);

        if (SymGetLineFromAddr64(process,~
                                 stack.AddrPC.Offset,
                                 &csEntry.offsetFromLine,~
                                 &line)) {
        }
        printf("Frame %lu:\n"
               "    Symbol name:    %s\n"
               "    PC address:     0x%08LX\n"
               "    Stack address:  0x%08LX\n"
               "    Frame address:  0x%08LX\n"
               "\n",
               frame,
               symbol.Name,
               (ULONG64)stack.AddrPC.Offset,
               (ULONG64)stack.AddrStack.Offset,
               (ULONG64)stack.AddrFrame.Offset
           );

        // If nothing else to do break loop
        if (!result) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```